# index.html won't show main.js code in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html

I was following along with a tutorial on how to show .js files on an index.html but javascript only shows when it's part of the index.html code rather than on a separate .js file. Chomre dev tools is picking up a syntaxerror though I'm not sure what it is. I have even tried opening up other people's github js work and have had no luck

I have checked browser restrictions

```
//main.js code from jsfile 
<script>
  document.body.innerHTML = "This is some content";
</script>

//html uses  src="js/main.js" in a script tag after <body> tag
```

Should show "This is some content" on web page

Comment: [edit] to add [mcve] please

Comment: do you put your main.js file inside `js` directory? (if no then change src to `src="main.js"`)

Comment: Syntax-errors are usually easy to find just by clicking the `line:row` next to the error in dev-tools.

Comment: if your js file contains `<script>` tags, as you have clearly shown it does, then it isn't a valid JS file, and the syntax error is because `<script>` isn't valid JS

Answer (score 2):

When you put JS code in a separate file, do not include the `<script>` tags; just the JavaScript:

```
// main.js
document.body.innerHTML = "This is some content";
```

Not like this:

```
// main.js
<script>
  document.body.innerHTML = "This is some content";
</script>
```

The `<script>` tags are used to separate the HTML/CSS from JS in an .htm file. A .js file should not have any HTML/CSS in it.